# Mongodb atlas: how to apply limit and sort using Atlas console's filter option

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I am using Mongodb Atlas and need to get the last 10 records. For which, have to apply a filter having sort and limit options. In mongo shell, we do it in this way:

```
db.category.find().sort( { name: 1 } ).limit( 5 )
```

or

```
db.category.find().limit( 5 ).sort( { name: 1 } )
```

How Mongodb Atlas console's filter option can be used for having the desired result? I didn't find any documentation for this, is it documented somewhere that how filter option can be used?

Comment: What atlas ui are you referring to?

Comment: I am using Mongodb atlas console and data explorer to filter. @D.SM

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions are available on the MongoDB atlas for your problem

**1. Connect your MongoDB atlas two command line.**
On the home page of the atlas, **click Connect**, then **Connect to Mongo Shell** so there you get the connection string to connect with the command line and fire query over there and get the required result.

**2. Create aggregate function on collection.**

**Click on the collection**, then you will find the option of aggregation so **click on Aggregation**
then 1st select $sort condition, then select $limit condition and get the required data.

Please refer to uploaded image:
[image: sample sort and limit condition on specific collection]